# HtmlAgilityPack XPath This is an unclosed string

Tags: c#, html, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need to parse a page and get inner text from specified textbox on that page. But, when I compiled this code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument infoDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["br"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
infoDoc.LoadHtml(@ProblemPageSource.ToString());
HtmlNode bodyGlobal = @infoDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//body").SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='global']");
HtmlNode globalRight = @bodyGlobal.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='globalRight']");
HtmlNode formPanel = @globalRight.SelectSingleNode(".//form").SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='panel]");
ProblemCode = @formPanel.SelectNodes(".//div")[0].SelectSingleNode(".//textarea").OuterHtml.ToString(); //And here is now NullRefEx :(
codeEditor.Text = @ProblemCode.ToString();
```

I had an exception throwed from Xpath with message "this string is unclosed".
And...source of the page I need to parse hosted at [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/sirkadirov/06a9c86569670a69d9c4).
UPD: Minimalistic version:
[Minimalistic version of the code viewed in the MozDevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anWoK.png)
Can anybody help me please?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english!
P.S.S. When I checked the code by W3C Validator there are no any unclose tags...but many errors (not my problem :) )
P.S.S.S. Yes, I am using CEFsharp to view the pages, and I get sources from him. So, if it uses autocorrection of Html, why this code is broken? :(

Comment: Please don't just include a link to the code that's giving you problems. Please include, within the body of your question, a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Bob Kaufman, OK. I'm just updated question.

Comment: Now I get NullReferenceException on line 7, but why? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the uncolsed single quote in in your `".//div[@class='panel]"`  you will need to call:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
```

Before you create an instance of your `HtmlDocument` because `form` elements are allowed to overlap  and thus handled differently, after that you'll be able to deal with forms as any other element.

so the following shall do:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
 HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["br"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
 var infoDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 infoDoc.LoadHtml(@ProblemPageSource.ToString());
 HtmlNode bodyGlobal = infoDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body//div[@class='global']");
 HtmlNode globalRight = @bodyGlobal.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='globalRight']");
 HtmlNode formPanel = @globalRight.SelectSingleNode(".//form//div[@class='panel']");
 var ProblemCode = @formPanel.SelectSingleNode(".//div/textarea").OuterHtml.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you, guy! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct `SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='panel]");` to `SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='panel']");`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But, now I have an other error, NullRefEx on line ProblemCode = @formPanel.SelectNodes(".//div")[1].SelectSingleNode(".//textarea").OuterHtml.ToString();